# Can we apply multiple psm modes to a single image in tesseract ocr

Tags: python-tesseract

pytesseract.image_to_string(imageopen, lang='eng',config='--psm 12')

can we apply one more psm in this code like
pytesseract.image_to_string(imageopen, lang='eng',config='--psm 12',config='--psm 6')

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: suppose my image may contain single word , multiple words, multiple words in different lines . which psm mode satisfy all these three cases and return accurate ocr . If there is no single psm that satisfy all these three cases , then im asking if i could use more than one psm mode while doing tesseract so that all those three cases will be satisfied